# findbugs-maven-plugin does not show bugs

Tags: maven, findbugs

the FindBugs Maven plugin does not create a bug report (target/findbugs.xml).

I have the following lines in pom.xml, in the build section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And among the other code I have this class:

```
public class ScrollingTextView extends TextView {

public ScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    myFunc(null);


    }

public String myFunc(int number) {
    return number+1;
}
}
```

I run either

```
mvn findbugs:findbugs
```

or
    mvn findbugs:check

I expect the bug to be spotted, but nothing is created in the target directory. Build is successful. Could you please advice how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't found a file findBugs.xml in target folder ? Either without or with the plugin configuration?

Comment: khmarbaise, yes, with and without the configuration

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the configuration from the POM's build section into the reporting section.  The examples in the [usage documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html) show the config this way.

`mvn site` should generate the reports.  Per the docs, `mvn findbugs:findbugs` "Generates a FindBugs Report when the site plugin is run."

If you want to fail the build if bugs are found, with an XML report, try `mvn findbugs:check`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, but mainly I do it because i use this plugin with Jenkins, and I don't know why but for some plugins it does not run site stage.

Comment: Make sure that `site` is specified as one of the Build Goals you want to execute in your Jenkins config for this project.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs the check goal is to fail the build if there are violation but you have to run the creation before. Apart from that the generation of findbugs is reporting which belong to site lyfecycle.

```
 <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```